# Using-password-based-encryption in android

Tags: android, encryption

The Code below  although works, but when i continuously run throws "Given final block not properly padded" some times and others as well. I feel that i making a small error some where.
Can you help me to resolve the issue?

Exception stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2086)
    at MCrypt.decrypt(MCrypt.java:87)
    at MCrypt.main(MCrypt.java:21)
```

And my code:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class MCrypt {

    private int iterationCount = 10000;
    private int saltLength = 8; // bytes; 64 bits
    private int keyLength = 128;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MCrypt mc = new MCrypt();
        String encryptedData = mc.encrypt("1234");
        MCrypt mc1 = new MCrypt();
        System.out.println(new String(mc1.decrypt(new String(encryptedData),
                "1234"), "UTF-8"));
    }

    public MCrypt() {
    }

    public String encrypt(String text) throws Exception {
        if (text == null || text.length() == 0)
            throw new Exception("Empty string");

        byte[] encrypted = null;

        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = new byte[saltLength];
        random.nextBytes(salt);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
        random.nextBytes(iv);
        IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(text.toCharArray(), salt,
                iterationCount, keyLength);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory
                .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        byte[] keyBytes = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivParams);

        encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        String encryptedStr = Base64.encodeBytes(encrypted);

        StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();
        strBuf.append(new String(encryptedStr));
        strBuf.append("]");
        strBuf.append(new String(salt));
        strBuf.append("]");
        strBuf.append(new String(iv));

        return new String(Base64.encodeBytes(strBuf.toString().getBytes()));
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(String code, String pwd) throws Exception {
        if (code == null || code.length() == 0)
            throw new Exception("Empty string");

        String[] fields = new String(Base64.decode(code)).split("]");
        byte[] cipherBytes = Base64.decode(fields[0]);
        byte[] salt = fields[1].getBytes();
        byte[] iv = fields[2].getBytes();

        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(pwd.toCharArray(), salt,
                iterationCount, keyLength);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory
                .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        byte[] keyBytes = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        byte[] decrypted = null;
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivParams);
        decrypted = cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);

        return decrypted;
    }

}
```

Comment: your methods don't make sense, the encrypt method seems to use the text to be encrypted to derive the key also. If your encrypt method takes Strings and returns Strings then so should your decrypt method.

Comment: i resolved the issue. StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();
  strBuf.append(encryptedStr);
  strBuf.append("]");
  String saltStr = Base64.encodeBytes(salt);
  strBuf.append(saltStr);
  strBuf.append("]");
  String ivStr = Base64.encodeBytes(iv);
  strBuf.append(ivStr);

Comment: yes that is the way i want it to be i wanted to this methodology "Using Password-based Encryption". hence the procedure. if you could suggest anything better than this i would appreciate.

Comment: So you posted total crap and I wasted my time on it?

Comment: why was it a crap? I put the resolution also. All i did not do is to encode the strings thatz all. hope you understand the code, if otherwise also leave it.... becoz i do...

Comment: GregS thanks for looking at the code.. sorry if i wasted ur time...

Comment: The encrypt function that you posted cannot encrypt data. It uses the data (`text`) to derive the encryption key. That's turns it into a hash function, rendering decryption impossible

Answer (score 0):

**Look at this**

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;

public class AesFileIo {
//    private static final String AES_ALGORITHM = "AES/CTR/NoPadding";
    private static final String AES_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec;
    private IvParameterSpec ivSpec;

    public AesFileIo(byte[] aesKey, byte[] iv) {
        ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES");
    }

    public String decrypt(String text) {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivSpec);
            byte[] decordedValue =  Base64.decode(text,Base64.DEFAULT);
            String decryptedValue = new String(cipher.doFinal(decordedValue),"UTF-8");
            Log.e("decrypted Value :",decryptedValue);
            return decryptedValue; 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public String encrypt(String text) {
        String encryptedValue=null;
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ALGORITHM); 
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivSpec);
            byte[] encValue = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
            encryptedValue = Base64.encodeToString(encValue,Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return encryptedValue;
    }
}
```

**How to use**

```
public static byte[] iv = { '0', '0','0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' };
    private static final byte[] keyValue = new byte[] { 'b', 'i', 'r', 'a', 'j', 'z', 'a', 'l', 'a', 'v', 'a', 'd', 'i', 'y', 'a', 'r' };
AesFileIo aes = new AesFileIo(keyValue, iv);
String encrypetedText = aes.encrypt(str);
String decryptedText = aes.decrypt(encrypetedText);

System.out.println("EncrypetedText : " + encrypetedText);
System.out.println("DecryptedText : " + decryptedText);
```

Comment: This is really an incomplete solution. I don't think you should be passing in a fixed iv vector of 0 values and the password bytes you supplied must be 16 in length

Comment: @ IcedDante please edit the answer and make it complete solution.